# Загрузка файла php

Tags: php

Файл загружается и выдает в конце что все прошло успешно но в папке файл не появляется.

Права выставлены

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/

{"Message":"The file 374.png has been uploaded.","Status":"OK"}
```

**Index.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
 Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

**Upload.php**

```
<?php

$target_path = dirname(getcwd()).'/img/';
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "The file ". basename($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
        "Status" => "OK"
    ]);
} else{
     echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
        "Status" => "Error"
    ]);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ошибку!
Указан не верный путь.

изменил - $target_path = dirname(getcwd()).'/img/';

на - $target_path = dirname(**FILE**).'/img/';